# Maven force update only for specific dependency (mvn -U for selected dependencies)

Tags: maven, maven-3

The command `mvn -U` forcing **all** project dependencies to get updated from remote repository.

Is it possible to force such update for specific selection of dependencies, by explicit selection / by some logic?

**The reasoning:**

I don't want to force checking all the dependencies we have because how time consuming it is. All I need, is to verify a few of them or even specify only one dependency. So, such solution is highly desired.

Comment: not by using the -U option. The maven-dependency-plugin has a "revolve" goal: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/resolve-mojo.html - it might be possible to use a combination of excludes and the includeArtifactIds to do this? The other option would be to delete the artifact and the meta-data files from the local repository. That should force maven to re-resolve that artifact as there is no more information available.

Comment: It's another question i'm don't know the answer for. Tried to figure out how it's possible but didn't find out.
About the deletion of data, that's what i'm doing now and what to stop to doing it. Feels too "manual" for me.

Comment: Would you like to update your pom file automatically somehow to select a particular newer version of a dependency? Correct?

Comment: Even without automatic pom update, just to select specific dependency to force update from remote repositories and not -U that  update everything. Is there a solution for this case?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There are two maven plugins that may help you here.

The first, **dependency**, will simply download the given version of a dependency:
`mvn dependency:get -Dartifact=groupId:artifactId:version`

The second, **versions**, offers some behaviors which you may also find helpful.

By running `mvn versions:use-latest-releases -Dincludes=groupId:artifactId` your project's pom will be updated with the latest release version of the dependency specified by the '-Dincludes' flag. You could then run the first command to download the version now referenced by your pom.

Both of these behaviors can be heavily customized and automated to do some quite awesome things. To get more help on a plugin goal, run: `mvn plugin:help -Ddetail=true -Dgoal=goal`

Example: `mvn versions:help -Ddetail=true -Dgoal=use-latest-releases`

For further information:
[versions](http://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/index.html), [dependency](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/), and [plugins](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Plugins)

Comment: Nice, looks like `dependency:get -Dartifact=groupId:artifactId:version` is exactly what I needed.